# Uniform distribution in a small range to generate precise big probability

Tags: php, probability

Currently I'm using a uniform distribution to generate a winning probability.

For a probability of let's say `1%` I define a winning number `47` then I do a `mt_rand(1,100)` and if the number is `47` the user win. Which is fine.

This work well for small probability like `1/100'000` but when I want a probability of let's say `40%` which is `1/0.4 = 2.5`

I cannot make `mt_rand(1,2.5)` I have to do `mt_rand(1,2)` or `mt_rand(1,3)` which mean respectively `50%` and `33%`.

How should I do to get a `40%` probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (mt_rand(1, 100) / $probability <= 1) {
    // success
}
```

E.g. if you have now `$probability = 10`; you have ten (of hundred) cases where the number between 1 and 100 is smaller or equal to one.

Comment: Okay I'm trying to understand your answer :) So actually it means that only when mt_rand() return a small enough number there is a win.

Answer (score 3):

let's say you want winning probability as x (assuming an integer), then generate

```
$num = mt_rand (1,100)
if ($num<=$prob) {//user wins}
```

If you don't have $prob as an integer and is a number with 2 decimal places eg: 47.23%, then you could generate

```
$num = mt_rand(1,10000)
if ($num/100 <= $prob), {//user wins}
```

Similarly you can extend it to whatever accuracy you want

Comment: Ya, He hadn't answered when I started posting. Anyways I've extended by including information on how to go about it when the winning probability is not an integer so this might help someone else

Comment: well in my case probability ar on per 100'000 with $prob between 1 and 100'000 so I just do if(mt_rand(1,100000) <= $prob) it's perfect fit and way better than what I used to do before!

Comment: Yes, you can just change the number in the parameter and use it for whatever probability scales you have